# TypeError: not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object Error accessing python

Tags: python

```
     return json.loads(ret.read())
    else:
        req['command'] = command
        req['nonce'] = int(time.time()*1000)
        post_data=urllib.parse.urlencode('utf-8')

        sign = hmac.new(self.Secret, post_data, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
        headers = {
            ("sign"): sign,
            ("key"): self.APIKey
        }

        headers = headers.encode('utf-8')
        ret = urllib.parse.urlencode('https://poloniex.com/tradingApi', post_data, headers)

        ret = urllib.request.urlopen()
        jsonRet = json.loads(ret.read())
        return self.post_process(jsonRet)
```

This is python code that connects to poloniex exchange to automate crypto trades. I'm get problem when it comes to this part. This code was written on python 2 and then i tried converting it for python 3.

Comment: Which line caused the error? what did the data look like3? Typically the full Traceback is expected as well as the data and offending code.

Comment: Is `.connects to poloniex exchange to automate crypto trades.`  relevant to the problem.